# Get ntp offset between local machine and ntp-server

Tags: sync, ntp, systemd-timesyncd

Using Ubuntu 18.04.3 I am unable to get information about the NTP offset using `timedatectl timesync-status` as I get a `Unknown operation timesync-status` prompt.
Checking the service state with `timedatectl` and `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` works just fine.
Is there another way to check the offset?

Comment: Not really helpful remark: on my 19.04 system `timedatectl timesync-status` does work although the autocompletion doesn't show the command.

Comment: FYI, the `timedatectl` command has evolved very quickly since 18.04 and the new features are not available in the old OS. (new features are not added retroactively).

Answer (score 1):

Although it may not be exactly what you have asked for, you can use the following method (no `sudo` is required):

```
$ /bin/journalctl --unit=systemd-timesyncd -n 1  | tail -1
Aug 16 15:57:13 xxxxxx systemd-timesyncd[958]: Synchronized to time server 169.254.169.254:123 (169.254.169.254).
```

With the command above, you determine the time server `timesyncd` is synchronized to. In this example, it is `169.254.169.254`.

Then you can use the command `ntpdate -q` with this server like this:

```
$ ntpdate -q 169.254.169.254
server 169.254.169.254, stratum 2, offset -0.000081, delay 0.02580
 1 Sep 12:20:24 ntpdate[3978]: adjust time server 169.254.169.254 offset -0.000081 sec
```

***Note***: You can install the `ntpdate` command, using `apt install ntpdate`.